# How do I get only the current users posts to show?

Tags: flutter, post, google-cloud-firestore, compare

I'm trying to build an app in flutter and I have come up against this problem which I can't seem to find any existing answers.  How do I get only the current users posts to show? My posts collection has a user id field which I want to compare with the current user and display only the post where the userId and currentUser are the same.

```
 return FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
        builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot) {
          if (futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, streamSnapshot) {
                if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                final documents = streamSnapshot.data.documents;

                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => PostItem(
                          documents[index]['title'],
                          documents[index]['imageUrl'],
                          documents[index]['location']['address'],
                        ));
              });
        });
```

[here is my post collection structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYb4O.jpg)

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  Please edit the question to better illustrate the data you're working with, and what you expect this code to do with that data.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently getting all posts with:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots()
```

If you only want posts for the current user, that'd be something like:

```
var uid = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).uid;
Firestore.instance.collection('posts').where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots()
```

The first line determines the UID of the current user, and then the second line uses that to request only documents whose `uid` field matches the value.

Comment: Hi, I've added a link to an image of the post-collection which has the userId field. When using your suggestion,  I'd need to use userId as ('uid', isEqualTo: userId) but userId isn't recognised.

Comment: In that case you 'll need to have a `FutureBuilder` for determing the UID and then **inside** that you'd have the `StreamBuilder` you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I hadn't but my future into a variable for the streambuilder where clause !! I was trying to use the original fireauth currentuser!

````
return FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
        builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot) {
          if (futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          **final String currentUser** = futureSnapshot.data.uid;
          return StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection('posts')
                  .where('userId', isEqualTo: **currentUser**)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, streamSnapshot) {
                if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                final documents = streamSnapshot.data.documents;

                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => PostItem(
                          documents[index]['userId'],
                          documents[index]['title'],
                          documents[index]['imageUrl'],
                          documents[index]['location']['address'],
                        ));
              });
        });


```
````